# react-pose: How do I define the types for props in react-pose? (props implicitly has any type)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-pose

I'm using TypeScript with [react-pose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pose) and need to define the typings for props. This is an application I just started with `create-react-app` version 3.0.1.

I keep getting the error `Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

I've tried Defining the type on the div similar to `styled-components`:

```js
const FadeIn = posed.div<{ duration: number; hiddenOffset: number }>({
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    scale: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    transition: { duration: props => props.duration }
  },
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    scale: 0.8,
    x: props => props.hiddenOffset,
    y: 10
  }
});
```

I've also tried defining a component to use in place of `posed.div`:

```js
const FadeInContainer: React.FC<{
  duration: number;
  hiddenOffset: number;
}> = props => {
  return <div {...props} />;
};
```

and passing it:

```js
const FadeIn = posed(FadeInContainer)({
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    scale: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    transition: { duration: props => props.duration }
  },
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    scale: 0.8,
    x: props => props.hiddenOffset,
    y: 10
  }
});
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining an interface for `props` and annotating the function argument seems to work.

```js
interface Props {
  duration: number;
  hiddenOffset: number;
}

const FadeIn = posed.div({
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    scale: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    transition: (props: Props) => ({ duration: props.duration })
  },
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    scale: 0.8,
    x: (props: Props) => props.hiddenOffset,
    y: 10
  }
});
```